# Angular ui-bootstrap accordion not working

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui

An example copied directly from
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Does not work at all, neither locally nor in plunker. Don't know why. Bootstrap CSS is loaded, so is ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js and angular.min.js (angular itself is working just fine though).
Here's the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/15GWWFSUwab4VmaxfFPf
I am getting no js errors in a browser, yet it's not working.
Please help. I need to get this working on my website (i.e. the accordion doesn't work even when I write my own html/js code).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A plunker created from the demo site works flawlessly, just created a plunker from the demo site: http://plnkr.co/edit/z9RQKgNBTRbigyQs7OGW?p=preview

In your plunker you are not declaring dependency on the `ui.bootstrap` module as described on the very top of the demo page:

> As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your
>   page you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.bootstrap module:
>   angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

After adding a dependency on the mentioned module your plunker works as well:
http://plnkr.co/edit/00bK0rNDYIrH9a9TVRk3?p=preview

One more thing - you need at least AngularJS 1.0.5 - there were bugs in earlier versions of AngularJS that prevented this directive from working correctly.

Comment: I had a gut feeling I missed something important. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got hung up on this same issue as well, but mine was a problem of being _too_ specific with what portions of `ui.bootstrap` that I was loading in. Even specifying `ui.bootstrap.accordion` isn't enough since that directive relies on other directives as well. Just load in `ui.bootstrap` to start and get more specific later once you have things working.