# Why is Angular ui-bootstrap accordion not working even after looking at other solutions?

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the same problem as the questions I have seen such as:
[Angular ui-bootstrap accordion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596580/angular-ui-bootstrap-accordion-not-working)

BUT the solution did not solve my problem.

Here is the code I have in plunker. In notepad++ the "accordion" is black. Not sure if that is relevant.
    `enter code here`http://plnkr.co/edit/6ea0esLpoLkBE6OBhKiK?p=preview

EDIT, adding files:

```
// create the module and name it calendarDemoApp
//var calendarDemoApp = angular.module('calenderDemoApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

// create the module and name it scotchApp

var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', [
'ngRoute',
//'ui.bootstrap'
//'ngAnimate'
])
// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'landing.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the settings page
        .when('/settings', {
            templateUrl : 'settings.html',
            controller  : 'settingsController'
        })

        .when('/find', {
            templateUrl : 'find.html',
            controller  : 'findController'
        })

        .when('/myReservation', {
            templateUrl : 'myReservation.html',
            controller  : 'myReservationController'
        });
        /*
        .when('/confirm',{
            templateUrl : 'confirm.html',
            controller  : 'confirmController'
        });*/
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.doTheBack = function($scope){
        window.history.back();

    };
    // create a message to display in our 
    $scope.message = 'Would you like reserve a room or search your reservations?';      
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('myReservationController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('settingsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Your account settings';
});

scotchApp.controller('findController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Here is your reservations.';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapse").click(function(){
            $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
        });
    }); 


});
```

The following is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="scotchApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Accordion test</title>
<script src="angular.js"/>
<script src="angular-route.js"/>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="landingScript.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="findController">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
Open only one at a time
</label>

<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<accordion-group heading="Static Header">
  This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
</accordion-group>
<accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
  <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
    <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
</div>
```

The following is bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "~1.4.1",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.4",
"angular-ui-calendar": "~1.0.1",
"fullcalendar": "~2.3.2",
"jquery": "~2.1.4",
"moment": "~2.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"angular-mocks": "~1.x",
"bootstrap-css": "2.3.1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you failed to integrate the solution into your application. You can't just copy paste.

The first step to your solution is to create the module to be used properly.

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('calendarDemoApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']
```

The code above is what is in the plunker. scotchApp is not used in the html and what you are looking to use is the code below.

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('calenderDemoApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate'])
```

This should fix the first problem. A few things i would look at is AccordionDemoCtrl not being defined properly and also you might run into problems with how the JavaScript files are loaded in. (order)

Comment: With some hints in your answer, I got my solution(maybe). http://plnkr.co/edit/mj3AOW0R87plk3k2Joxs?p=preview

Comment: Nope, nevermind. This is still not being able to do accordion things.

Comment: what accordion things? it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: The accordion works on plunker but it doesn't when I run it locally on my machine with my htmls/scripts.

Comment: If the code in the OP is still correct then you need to load in angular.min.js before the other angular scripts. This is because the the other modules depend on angular. If the order is correct then you check out the console and see if there are any errors about the scripts not being found.

Comment: If I use the code from here, http://plnkr.co/edit/mj3AOW0R87plk3k2Joxs?p=preview
It would not show up as an accordion however, if I just load find.html directly, it would. Here's some screenshots. http://i.imgur.com/jTpr6aa.png 
http://i.imgur.com/P5v6mrU.png